# Bring to front Object flash actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a button and four stacked movieclips. What action should I put in my button if I want to bring the movieclip in the bottom to the front?

Comment: you can just do:  `addChild(bottomItem);` to bring something to the front.  Beware though, when you tweak a timeline created object's parentage (eg you use addChild/addChildAt/setChildIndex) that object will no longer respond to timeline keyframes and will have to be manipulated through code from then on.

Answer (score 0):

```
setChildIndex(myChild,numChildren);
```

this code moves your display object to the front of others.

I  H☻ P E  this helps.